# Sympifying strings containing expressions with superscripts

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to sympify a string like these

```
str1="a^0_0"
ns={}
ns['a^0_0']=Symbol('a^0_0')
pprint(sympify(str1,locals=ns))
```

But I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cuaterniones_basic.py", line 114, in <module>
    pprint(sympify(str1,locals=ns))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/core/sympify.py", line 356, in sympify
    raise SympifyError('could not parse %r' % a, exc)
sympy.core.sympify.SympifyError: Sympify of expression 'could not parse u'a^0_0'' failed, because of exception being raised:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1
```

How can get the symbol I want?

Comment: AFAIK, the symbols available in sympy are the same as identifiers in Python. You might be able to define a symbol like a**4 but sympy will fail to parse a polynomial equation involving this symbol in some contexts, at least. Moreover, any string that you send to `sympify` must be a legitimate sympy expression, which `str1` is not.

Comment: @BillBell The only requirement on the _name_ of a SymPy symbol is to be a string. It can have spaces, newlines, be empty, etc. Try `a = Symbol('\n\n\n'); expand((a+1)**3)`

Comment: @if....: I *should* have written 'you can define a symbol like a**4 (etc) ...' I actually tried this. Shove that into an expression in `solve` and sympy coughs.

Comment: The other answer is better, you may want to move the checkmark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the parser makes a decision about the structure of your input string before it comes to converting pieces to SymPy atoms. 
There are a bunch of knobs one can twist by using [parse_expr](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html) instead of sympify but I haven't found one that works for this string. Instead, it may be easiest to preprocess the input with string replacement, replacing the troublesome characters with something else. This preprocessing doesn't affect the final outcome because the dictionary `ns` will make things right again.

```
str1 = "a^0_0"
new_str1 = str1.replace("^", "up")
ns = {new_str1: Symbol(str1)}
print(sympify(new_str1, locals=ns))
```

Prints `a^0_0` which is the name of the created symbol.

Answer (score 2):

`sympify` can only parse expressions if they are valid Python (with a few minor exceptions). That means that symbol names can only be parsed if they are valid Python variable names. The solution depends on the exact nature of what you are trying to parse.

- If the whole string is the symbol name, just use `Symbol` instead of `sympify`.
- If you are constructing the Symbol objects from known strings, wrap them in `Symbol('...')` in your string, like `sympify("Symbol('a^0') + 1")`.
- If you know what characters you will see, you can try swapping them before parsing, then swapping them back in the expression with `replace`.

  ```
  >>> sympify('a^0 + 1'.replace('^', '__').replace(lambda a: isinstance(a, Symbol), lambda a: Symbol(a.name.replace('__', '^')))
  a^0 + 1
  ```

  (don't confuse `str.replace` and SymPy's `expr.replace` here).

  This will not work if the characters in your symbol names are also used to represent math outside of the symbol names (like if you use `^` to represent actual exponentiation).
- In general, you may need to write your own parsing tool. SymPy's parsing utilities in `sympy.parsing` can help here.